# Create Randomized levels in BGE

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, workflow

Right now I'm working on a random dungeon generator. In the game so far, I can  randomize the placement of a ton of cubes. how can is get them to respond to each-other so they know if there are other cubes in a certain direction?

That doesn't make sense, so lets say it like this. A cube has four sides, and four diagonals, so essentially, there are up to 8 spaces around that cube. How can I sense when there are neighboring cubes and if so, which spot(s) they occupy? Here's my BA thread http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?381600-Randomized-dungeon

I pulled this snippet from nines, who's helped me a ton, but I don't understand it. if this could be explained *and it works for my situation* I will accept that as an answer also.

```
def check_neighbors(self, x,y):
        num = 0
        #check cardinal neighbors
        if self.isValid(x,y+1):
            if self.map[x][y+1].block:
                num += 1

        if self.isValid(x,y-1):
            if self.map[x][y-1].block:
                num += 1

        if self.isValid(x-1,y):
            if self.map[x-1][y].block:
                num += 1

        if self.isValid(x+1,y):
            if self.map[x+1][y].block:
                num += 1

        #check diagonals too! Diagonal neighbors = instant fail
        '''                    
        if self.isValid(x+1,y+1):
            if self.map[x+1][y+1].block:
                num = 0

        if self.isValid(x-1,y+1):
            if self.map[x-1][y+1].block:
                num = 0

        if self.isValid(x+1,y-1):
            if self.map[x+1][y-1].block:
                num = 0

        if self.isValid(x-1,y-1):
            if self.map[x-1][y-1].block:
                num = 0
        '''                
        return num
```

**NOTE:** that code says diagonals are not accepted *I want to be able to sense and exploit diagonals also!!!*

Comment: What he descripes is basically a bit mask for each tile. For n,e,s,w you assign 4 bits. If you need more directions - ne,nw,se,sw you need 4 more bits and so on. E.g. 10100001 means neighbors in n,s and sw. In this example n is represented by the highest bit (128), south (32) and sw(1). Of course you could do even easier and represent the map by an 2 dimensional array and just check the indices around the location you are interested in (like image processing).

Comment: Yes, but my question is how to do that. how can cubes sense their neighbors?

Comment: Cubes do not sense other objects. Sensors can do that. The above example assumes your game model is Python data structure (list of lists). The processing runs on that model rather than in 3D space. If you want it in 3D space you can for example check with a ray is there is an detectable object or not.